# How to change GitHub account name in commits

Tags: git, github, git-bash

I've changed user name on GitHub, after that I've cloned one of my repos and made some commits using git bash. After I pushed changes and found that my old user name was in commits. How to fix it?

P.S. In credential manager in control panel I see that I've logged to git bash using my new user name.

Comment: `git config [--global] user.name myname` doesn't work, git says that such key doesn't exist, but `git config --global user.name myname` works thanks

Comment: @Mushroomator, could you explain me in quick way what's difference between `[--global]` and `--global`?

Comment: Yes `[ ]` only says that this argument is optional. Because you can also set a local git config so it's not expected to work with `[ ]`. You might wanna have a look at this [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Backus%E2%80%93Naur_form). This notation is usually used for describing the API of many CLI applications.

Comment: And if I work with remote repo?

Comment: Your local git config will determine what user/ email your commits will be labelled with. You will have to authenticate though if you want to commit to Github or alike.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Execute this command

`git config --global user.name mynewusername`

Comment: Thanks that helped. I tried [--global] first but git said that such key doesn't exist.